# Prevent WordPress to remove my variables added in my url (custom post type)

Tags: php, wordpress, url, custom-post-type, urlvariables

Do you know why WordPress delete variables when I'm on a page of "custom post types" (singular) and not when I'm on a standard page?

Here is how I create my URL in a loop.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'p', $url, the_permalink() ) ); ?>">See more</a>
```

The link is generated correctly, but when I click "?p=value" is deleted...

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that you're using "`the_permalink()`" which outputs the value itself.

You need to use `get_the_permalink()` function.

Your new code will look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'a', $url, get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>">See more</a>
```

**Update:**

Plus, you're trying to retain `?p=xxx` in your url. WordPress takes `p` as a post id variable, and thus it uses it and uses permalink rewrite rules to redirect and remove this from the url.

You will retain the query variable if you use anything other than `?p=` , try `?a=something` e.g.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. (but it is getting better, so thank you)
For information, if I manually added "?p=value" in the url bar, this part is automatically deleted.

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: this is because "p" is used by wordpress to show the post, it will retain any other variable, try ?a=something

Comment: you're welcome :) I've added this to the answer too. please mark the ans as correct and also upvote if it was useful :)